# Detect left and right mouse click on NSView

Tags: swift, nsview, nsevent

In Swift: I created a simple NSView and now want to execute different functions, depending on which mouseButton is pressed (left or right). how can I detect this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You trap the corresponding `mouseDown` events

```
import Cocoa

class MyView : NSView {
    override func mouseDown(theEvent : NSEvent) {
        println("left mouse")
    }

    override func rightMouseDown(theEvent : NSEvent) {
        println("right mouse")
    }
}
```

See [NSResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html) for more magic.

**Swift 4**

```
import Cocoa

class MyView : NSView {
    override func mouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        print("left mouse")
    }

    override func rightMouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        print("right mouse")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I adapt this custom class? Or is it overriding every NSView? I declared the NSView like `let theView = NSView()`. But I think I have to specify that my variable depends to the `MyView`?

Comment: NSView by itself isn't that useful except as a container for other views. It's one of things you generally subclass to get the behaviour you need . In your case you are detecting left and right clicks and doing something with them.

Comment: Solved my problem and also... I learned a lot about subclassing. Thank you so much!